# Switch user in a terminal window on a Mac

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

Could anybody help with simple question.
I need login/switch user in command line in 1 line; For example:
`login -p username ? password`.

What should I write at '?' position? Because I need to login in script which don't know id system asked password...

Answer (score 38):

You could try to use

```
su - username
```

in order to switch to the user you want.

You can find more documentation about `su` command [here](http://www.linfo.org/su.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the password to sudo like this:

```
echo "p@sw0rd" | sudo -S cal -y 2011
```

The example above runs 'cal -y 2011' with root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure you cant use `login` non-interactively (same for `su`) unless youre logging in as the already logged in user or unless the `login` command is invoked by root. However, if you meet either one of those requirements you would use the `-f` switch.

`man` Page: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/login/

you could of course use `ssh` but it seems wrong to ssh locally... You could also use [`expect`](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) to script the interactive login process.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably investigate `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dscl . list /Users | grep -v “^_”
```

That helps to see user list (mac)
for userx `su - userx` backt o root `sudo -i`